# ReactJs: Group data by today, current week, current year

Tags: reactjs

I have data in the following format

```
[
0:{
address:n/a
booking_status:null
commission_total:"65000.00"
created_at;"Tue, Jun, 2020"
},
1:{
address:n/a
booking_status:null
commission_total:"68000.00"
created_at;"Thur, Jun, 2020"
}
]
```

I am looking to group the set of data as described the subject line in ReactJs. Will anyone assist please

Comment: Does the month of June 2020 only have one Tuesday and only one Thursday? My calendar must be broken.

Comment: By group data you mean to have a function with a parameter ['toDay', 'thisWeek', 'currentYear'], and return an array with according data?

Comment: @YoandryCollazo thats correct

Comment: @HMR thats just sample data.

Comment: @Paul You should get a better sample because it's not possible to say what week those dates are in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use some sort of library for handling dates, like `date-fns` which have some builtin functions like `isSameWeek` and `isSameYear`

https://date-fns.org/v2.0.0-alpha.2/docs/isSameYear

Then it will be easy as filtering the array and extracting the ones that match

```
const today = new Date();

const todayGroup = data.filter(item => isSameDay(new Date(item.created_at), today));
const weekGroup = data.filter(item => isSameWeek(new Date(item.created_at), today));
const yearGroup = data.filter(item => isSameYear(new Date(item.created_at), today));
```

Comment: This is my preferred answer. But how do i make it return value instead of a boolean

Comment: I am finding it strange that this date `created_at :"Tue, Jun, 2020" ` is not identified as `isSameWeek`. and `created_at :"Wed, Jul, 2020" ` is not identified as today. Here is the code `const thisWeekBookings = data.filter((booking) =>
        isSameWeek(new Date(booking.created_at), today)
      );`

Comment: You will need to add a day to your dates, `Tue, Jun, 2020` could be any Tuesday in June, so it will be difficult to know if it is the same day, or week

Comment: i have changed the format to this `created_at:"2, Jun, 2020" ` Not working

Comment: I edited the answer, you need to create new Date objects using your date strings before comparing them

Comment: Niice..i was sending wrong date in the api. Thank you very much for assistance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment

```
var REFERENCE = moment("2015-06-05"); // fixed just for testing, use moment();
var TODAY = REFERENCE.clone().startOf('day');
var YESTERDAY = REFERENCE.clone().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day');
var A_WEEK_OLD = REFERENCE.clone().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day');

function isToday(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isSame(TODAY, 'd');
}
function isYesterday(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isSame(YESTERDAY, 'd');
}
function isWithinAWeek(momentDate) {
    return momentDate.isAfter(A_WEEK_OLD);
}
function isTwoWeeksOrMore(momentDate) {
    return !isWithinAWeek(momentDate);
}

console.log("is it today? ..................Should be true: "+isToday(moment("2015-06-05")));
console.log("is it yesterday? ..............Should be true: "+isYesterday(moment("2015-06-04")));
console.log("is it within a week? ..........Should be true: "+isWithinAWeek(moment("2015-06-03")));
console.log("is it within a week? ..........Should be false: "+isWithinAWeek(moment("2015-05-29")));
console.log("is it two weeks older or more? Should be false: "+isTwoWeeksOrMore(moment("2015-05-30")));
console.log("is it two weeks older or more? Should be true: "+isTwoWeeksOrMore(moment("2015-05-29")));
```